# Xcode 4.6 - Integer multiplying by four itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I try to add 1 to the value "Clicks" and print it out, it becomes 4.

sclicks is my label, and clicks is the integer.

```
-(IBAction)Click:(id)sender {
clicks = clicks + 1;
sclicks.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Clicks: %d", clicks];
}
```

The clicks are of course linked to my button in the XIB. I'm basically trying to make it one someone clicks on the button, it updates the int to add one, and then update the label in the XIB. When I run it and hit the button, the label reads: "Clicks: 4", when it should read "Clicks: 1". When I SET clicks to one and not add to it, it works perfectly. I've also tried clicks++.

My .h file:

```
@interface ClickIt : ViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *clicks;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sclicks;

@end
```

Comment: Where is `clicks` defined? Where else is it updated, if anywhere? Can you post code for that?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on that code does it get called 4 times every click?

Comment: If `clicks` instance variable, then you found a reason to use properties instead. With property you just override setter, put a breakpoint in it and you see all changes with call stack.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob at xcode, could you please explain a breakpoint? And I did add my .h file @woz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property should declared as:

`@property (nonatomic) NSInteger clicks;`

I removed the *. What you had is a pointer to an NSInteger. When you increment that by one, the actual address increments by 4, since NSIntegers happen to be 4 bytes long on this platform.

Comment: good point. `NSInteger *` increments by four because NSInteger is four bytes wide.

Comment: Oh wow, silly me. Thanks. I am really new to Xcode, so I'm still getting the hang of the syntaxes and stuff.

Comment: Also Outlets should be weak ` @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *sclicks;`